# Not able to use table.column%type while creating varray in pl sql

Tags: plsql

I am trying to create below varray but getting error as "table.column" must be declared.

```
create or replace TYPE ARY_ABC AS VARRAY(15) OF TABLE.COLUMN%TYPE;
```

If I directly use datatype of TABLE.COLUMN it works perfectly fine. Does `VARRAY` not  support the `%type` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the SQL language that doesn't support the `%TYPE` notation. This is a PL/SQL feature, in which the compiler looks up the type details at compile time and builds the required code for you. There is no equivalent in SQL, other than `create as select` for tables and views.

Edit, following comments:

> Are you saying that during compilation, the compiler will find the meaning of `TYP_USER_DEFINED_OBJECT` but not the `TABLE.COLUMN%TYPE`?

No. The PL/SQL compiler looks up the details for `%TYPE` expressions at compile time and builds the required code for you, as if you had typed all the VARCHAR2s and NUMBERs etc yourself. `TYP_USER_DEFINED_OBJECT` on the other hand, is defined and published by the SQL `CREATE TYPE` statement. You can treat that as part of the SQL language.

By the way, `table` is generally a more useful collection type than `varray`, unless the limit of 15 is overwhelmingly useful for enforcing some rule.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Indeed i have requirement to put the the limit of 15.
Just curious, if we declare varray as below it works fine. Even though i am using sone user defined object. Are saying that during compilation, compiler will find the meaning of TYP_USER_DEFINED_OBJECT but not the TABLE.COLUMN%TYPE.

create or replace TYPE ARY_ABC AS VARRAY(15) OF TYP_USER_DEFINED_OBJECT;

Comment: Pardon me...but who is Bill here? :-)

Comment: The PL/SQL language has a compiler that is completely separate from the SQL language. SQL is parsed and transformed and optimised etc, but there is no compilation in the sense that Java and PL/SQL have it. (And who's Bill?)